# details for or details about?

Tags: word-usage

i have just read this sentence which seems strange to me, because I couldn't find  "details for" in dictionary:

-He just turned up out of the blue sky, so we haven't got any details for him.

Is the sentence mentioned correct?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! There are a couple of typos in your title and sentence (deltails, bluse, detalis). I assume those were not intended, but you should probably [edit] your question to fix those and make it clear that you're only asking about the usage of "details for" in this context, rather than whether the entire sentence is correct in every possible way.

Answer (score 1):

This is idiomatic but uncommon.

The sense here is that the details are necessary to provide whatever benefit the person is requesting. They may or may not be about "him" directly, but they are for "his" benefit.

Comment: So you mean that I had better not use "for"?

Comment: As the other answer says "details about," "details on," and "details for" are all idiomatic and all mean "details pertaining to." However, "details for" is not common, at least in my region of the US. I would use it only when describing those details that are relevant for a purpose, particularly a beneficial purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You could encounter any of the following prepositions there:

details on him

details about him

details for him

They all mean pretty much the same thing: details that pertain to him.

Comment: Strictly speaking, I don't think these mean the same thing, as they're stated here. I'd read the first two as describing information about a certain subject (him) and would interpret the third as describing an intended recipient (him) of information.

Comment: @tiffon: "for" can indeed be used as you have suggested, but it can also be used as indicated in the answer.  "Have you mailed them the specs *for the new ventilation system*?"   The new ventilation system is not a recipient but the thing to which the specs refer, or the thing the specs describe and prescribe.